# POO hacer que una clase valide la existencia de un usuario

Tags: java, array, poo, bucle-for, diseño-de-clases

Quisiera saber si pueden darme una luz con un programa de tarea que realizo. El programa contiene 3 clases llamadas CuentasBanco, testBanco y Agencia (esta contiene el main). Una de las funciones del main es agregar cuentas de banco y usuarios en un arreglo unidimensional; sin embargo, antes de agregar los usuarios este debe validar que no esten repetidos. Ya he intentado varias maneras, pero no he tenido exito. Espero alguien me pueda dar una mano!

Saludos y gracias de antemano!

Clase CuentasBanco

```
public class CuentasBanco {

//Atributos
private int codigo;
private String nombre;
private double saldo;

//Constructor
//Ex. CuentasBanco id=new CuentasBanco(12,"Yahir")
public CuentasBanco(int codigo, String nombre) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.saldo = 500;
}

//Set y Get

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

//Funciones Especificas
public void depositar(double monto) {
    if (monto > 0)
        saldo += monto;
}

public boolean retirar(double monto) {
    if (monto > 0 && monto <= saldo) {
        saldo -= monto;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void imprimir() {
    Calendar fecha_ahora = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("****Boleta del cliente****\n" +
            "Codigo: " + codigo + "\n" +
            "Nombre: " + nombre + "\n" +
            "Saldo: " + saldo + "Lps" +
            "Fecha " + fecha_ahora.getTime());
}
```

}

Clase testBanco

```
public class testBanco {
CuentasBanco cuentas[];
public double TASA=0.07;

public testBanco(int cantidad){
    cuentas=new CuentasBanco[cantidad];
}


//Buscar 2 por tipo entero
public int buscar(int codigo){
    for(int i=0;i<cuentas.length;i++){
        if(cuentas[i]!=null && cuentas[i].getCodigo()==codigo)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

//Crear una Cuenta del Cliente
public boolean crearCuenta(int codigo,String cliente){
    if(buscar(codigo)==-1){
        for(int i=0;i< cuentas.length;i++){
            if(cuentas[i]==null){
                cuentas[i]=new CuentasBanco(codigo,cliente);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public void transferir(int codigoOrigen,int codigoDestino,double monto){
    int origen= buscar(codigoOrigen);
    int destino= buscar(codigoDestino);

    if(origen!=-1 && destino!=-1){
        if(cuentas[origen].retirar(monto))
            cuentas[destino].depositar(monto);
        System.out.println("Fondos transferidos correctamente");
    }

}

public void intereses(){
    for(CuentasBanco cb:cuentas){
        if(cb!=null)
            cb.depositar(cb.getSaldo()*TASA);
    }
}
public void listar(double monto){
    for (CuentasBanco cb:cuentas){
        if(cb!=null && cb.getSaldo()>=monto)
            cb.imprimir();
    }
}
```

}

y la clase Agencia (main)

public class Agencia {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    testBanco cuentasBancarias = new testBanco(10);
    int opcion, cuentaOrigen, cuentaDestino, numeroCuenta;
    String nombreCliente;
    double monto = 0, intereses;


    System.out.println("***| BIENVENIDO AL SISTEMA DE AGENCIAS BANCARIAS ***|");


    do {
        System.out.println("\n*** M E N U ***\n");
        System.out.println("1. Agregar una cuenta");
        System.out.println("2. Transferir un monto a otra cuenta");
        System.out.println("3. Agregar intereses a las cuentas");
        System.out.println("4. Listar cuentas por un rango de monto");
        System.out.println("5. Salir");
        System.out.print("Ingrese Opcion: ");
        opcion = leer.nextInt();


        switch (opcion) {
            case 1: {
                System.out.println("\nAgregar una cuenta");
                System.out.print("Ingrese el numero de cuenta: ");
                numeroCuenta = leer.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Ingrese nombre del cliente: ");
                nombreCliente = leer.next();
                break;
            }

            case 2: {
                System.out.println("\nTransferir montos entre cuentas");
                System.out.print("Ingrese el monto que desea transferir de una cuenta a otra: ");
                monto = leer.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Ingrese el codigo de la cuenta origen: ");
                cuentaOrigen = leer.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Ingrese el codigo de la cuenta destino: ");
                cuentaDestino = leer.nextInt();
                break;
            }

            case 3: {
                System.out.println("Agregar intereses a las cuentas");


            }

            case 4:
                System.out.println("Listar cuentas por un rango de monto");
                cuentasBancarias.listar(monto);
                break;

            case 5:
                System.out.println("Gracias por usar el sistema de agencias");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Opcion no soportada");
                break;
        }

    } while (opcion != 5);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver si te puede servir mi idea

Está limitada a contestar sin desarrollar nada más, solo una forma de validar un usuario y una contraseña

```
//creamos una clase Cliente
public class Cliente {
    //Yo he pensado en éstos datos, pero a gusto del consumidor, jeje
    String nombre;
    String apellidos;
    String dni;
    String usuario;
    String password;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder cli = new StringBuilder();                                                                   
        cli.append("\nNombre: ");
        cli.append(nombre);
        cli.append("\nApellidos: ");
        cli.append(apellidos);
        cli.append("\nDNI: ");
        cli.append(dni);
        cli.append("\nUsuario: ");
        cli.append(usuario);  
        cli.append("\nPassword: ");
        cli.append(password); 
        return cli.toString();
    }   

    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }
    public String getApellidos(){
        return apellidos;
    }
    public String getDNI(){
        return dni;
    }
    public String getUsuario(){
        return usuario;
    }
    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public void setApellidos(String apellidos){
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }
    public void setDNI(String dni){
        this.dni = dni;
    }
    public void setUsuario(String usuario){
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }   
}
```

La clase Agencia

```
public class Agencia {
    //declaramos el array list que recogerá los clientes
    static ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        TestBanco cuentasBancarias = new TestBanco(10);
    
        //declaramos los String que usaremos para los datos del ArryList
        String nombre, apellidos, dni, usuario, password;
        int opcion, cuentaOrigen, cuentaDestino, numeroCuenta;
        String nombreCliente;
        double monto = 0, intereses;
        //variable booelana para evaluar el usuario
        boolean user;
    
        //Variable auxiliar que contendrá la referencia a cada cliente nuevo.
        Cliente cli;

        System.out.println("***| BIENVENIDO AL SISTEMA DE AGENCIAS BANCARIAS ***|");

        do {
            System.out.println("\n*** M E N U ***\n");
            System.out.println("1. Alta usuario");
            System.out.println("2. Agregar una cuenta");
            System.out.println("3. Transferir un monto a otra cuenta");
            System.out.println("4. Agregar intereses a las cuentas");
            System.out.println("5. Listar cuentas por un rango de monto");
            System.out.println("6. Salir");
            System.out.print("Ingrese una opcion: ");
            opcion = leer.nextInt();
            leer.nextLine();

            switch (opcion) {
                //agregamos un nuevo case que registre los datos de cada cliente
                case 1: {
                    System.out.println("\nPonga su nombre");
                    nombre = leer.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Ponga sus apelllidos: ");
                    apellidos = leer.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Introduzca su dni: ");
                    dni = leer.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Que usario desea utilizar: ");
                    usuario = leer.nextLine();
                    user = metodoComprobarExisteUsuario(usuario);
                    while (user == false) {
                        System.out.print("Lo siento, el usuario ya está en uso, introduzca uno nuevo: ");
                         usuario = leer.nextLine();
                        user = metodoComprobarExisteUsuario(usuario);
                    }
                    System.out.print("Introduzca una contraseña: ");
                    password = leer.nextLine();
                
                    //Se crea un objeto Cliente y se asigna su referencia a cli                  
                    cli = new Cliente();         

                    //se asignan valores a los atributos del nuevo objeto
                    cli.setNombre(nombre);
                    cli.setApellidos(apellidos);
                    cli.setDNI(dni);
                    cli.setUsuario(usuario);
                    cli.setPassword(password);
                  
                    //se añade el objeto al final del array
                    clientes.add(cli);
                    break;
                }
            
                case 2: {
                    System.out.println("\nAgregar una cuenta");
                    System.out.print("Ingrese usuario: ");
                    usuario = leer.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Ingrese password: ");
                    password = leer.nextLine();
                    boolean entrada = metodoComprobarUsuario(usuario, password);
                    if (entrada == true){
                        System.out.print("Ingrese el numero de cuenta: ");
                        numeroCuenta = leer.nextInt();
                        leer.nextLine();
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.print("Lo siento, sus datos no son correctos");
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                case 3: {
                    System.out.println("\nTransferir montos entre cuentas");
                    System.out.print("Ingrese el monto que desea transferir de una cuenta a otra: ");
                    monto = leer.nextDouble();
                    System.out.print("Ingrese el codigo de la cuenta origen: ");
                    cuentaOrigen = leer.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Ingrese el codigo de la cuenta destino: ");
                    cuentaDestino = leer.nextInt();
                    break;
                }

                case 4: {
                    System.out.println("Agregar intereses a las cuentas");
                }

                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Listar cuentas por un rango de monto");
                    cuentasBancarias.listar(monto);
                    break;

                case 6:
                    System.out.println("Gracias por usar el sistema de agencias");
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Opcion no soportada");
                    break;
            }

        } while (opcion != 6);
    }

    //Construimos el método que evaluará el usuario y la contraseña
    private static boolean metodoComprobarUsuario(String usuario, String password) {
        //creamos una variable booelana a false
        boolean entrada = false;
        //creamos un bucle que recorra el arrayList
        for(int i = 0; i < clientes.size(); i++){
            //Evaluamos que tanto el usuario y la contraseña exista en el arrayList, en este caso ignoramos minúsculas y mayúsculas, pero a gusto del consumidor
            if ((clientes.get(i).getUsuario().equalsIgnoreCase(usuario)) && (clientes.get(i).getPassword().equalsIgnoreCase(password))) {
                //si existen los datos damos el valor true a la variable
                entrada = true;
            }
        }
        //retornamos la variable
        return entrada;
    }
    //método que evalúa si el usuario existe
    private static boolean metodoComprobarExisteUsuario(String usuario) {
        //declaramos variable booleana a true
        boolean entrada = true;
        //bucle que recorre el arrayList
        for(int i = 0; i < clientes.size(); i++){
            //si el usuario existe
            if (clientes.get(i).getUsuario().equalsIgnoreCase(usuario)) {
                //damos el valor false a la variable
                entrada = false;
            }
        }
        //retornamos la variable
        return entrada;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola! de verdad agradezco todo el soporte, pude resolver todo siguiendo sus consejos! Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

## Comentarios

Como estás aprendiendo sólo te dejo unos pequeños tips que puedes o no aplicar.

- Probablemente te sea más útil para las siguientes acciones tener un [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) en vez de un [Array](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html)
- Es mejor [sobrescribir](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) el método [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()), aunque el método imprimir que tienes está perfectamente bien. Esto lo comento porque si te interesa puedes ir investigando un poco más de POO

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    return id + "\t\t" + name + "\t\t$ " + account_balance;
}
```

## Código ejemplo

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BankAccount Luis = new BankAccount(1, "Luis", 50);
        BankAccount Lorena = new BankAccount(2, "Lorena", 90);
        Bank bank = new Bank();
        if(bank.addAccount(Luis))
            System.out.println("Me registré");
        if(bank.addAccount(Luis))
            System.out.println("Me registré");
        else
            System.out.println("Esta segunda vez no me pude registrar");
        if(bank.addAccount(Lorena))
            System.out.println("Me registré");
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        bank.printAccounts();

    }

    private static class Bank {
        ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<>();

        protected boolean addAccount(BankAccount account) {
            for (BankAccount temp : accounts)
                if(account.getId() == temp.getId())
                    return false;
            accounts.add(account);
            return true;
        }

        protected void printAccounts() {
            for (BankAccount account: accounts) {
                System.out.println(account);
            }
        }
    }

    private static class BankAccount {
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private double account_balance;

        public BankAccount(int id, String name, double account_balance) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.account_balance = account_balance;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return id + "\t\t" + name + "\t\t$ " + account_balance;
        }
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Me registré
Esta segunda vez no me pude registrar
Me registré

----------------------

1       Luis        $ 50.0
2       Lorena      $ 90.0
```

**Anotaciones**

1. Lo de `private static class` ignóralo por el momento, puedes tratarlas como si fueran clases en otros archivos
2. Los *ArrayList* te permiten manejar arreglos de tamaño dinámico, es decir, pueden crecer o disminuir en tamaño de acuerdo a lo que se necesite.

La parte importante es la siguiente:

```java
protected boolean addAccount(BankAccount account) {
    for (BankAccount temp : accounts)
        if(account.getId() == temp.getId())
            return false;
    accounts.add(account);
    return true;
}
```

Donde verás que sólo tienes que hacer un *if* para saber si se repite o no la cuenta